# Heroku/Django - ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a site I made using Django to Heroku. Heroku says it's deploying but when I try to view it says "Application Error" and when I check my logs I'm seeing "ImportError: No module named restroomrater.wsgi".

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn restroomrater.wsgi --log-file -
```

**requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.2.10
cachetools==4.1.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.8
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.9.1
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
google-api-core==1.21.0
google-auth==1.19.0
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-storage==1.29.0
google-resumable-media==0.5.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.10
protobuf==3.12.2
psycopg2==2.8.5
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
rsa==4.6
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.9
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

**structure**
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B9go.jpg) <sorry, not sure how to get text version of the structure.

Everything I've looked up points to this being problem but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? "restroomrater" is the name of my app. Let me know if there's more info I can provide.

[restromrater dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLuDP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your Procfile is wrong.

```
web: uvicorn config.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT --workers $WEB_CONCURRENCY
```

`config` in my example is the name of the Django app. `asgi` is the name of asgi.py file, and `application` is the instance within that file. For gunicorn it's similar, but with wsgi.py.

Might be `appname.wsgi.application`, with the dot. I recommend uvicorn though for Django 3.

Comment: okay I changed it to what you said and now I'm getting "Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module 'restroomrater.asgi'"

Comment: What's the content of `restroomrater` dir?

Comment: added it to the original question

Comment: Yeah i stopped my original error but now seeing this new one

Comment: Okay so I can get it to work locally when I just use "web: uvicorn [myapp].asgi:application" without everything else after it, but i'm assuming leaving that out is why it' not working when deployed"

Comment: No need to leave it out. Just add `web: ` before and my settings starting with `--host` after.

Comment: Okay, i think the errors i’m getting at this point are unrelated to my original question. I’ve definitely made some progress with your help, so thank you!